# Rename stored procedure multiple columns after execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

After execution of my stored procedure, the following columns are returned:

- srno
- name
- days
- amount
- bkt1
- bkt2

but I want to change these column names to:

- srno
- name
- days
- amount
- col_name_i/p_from_user
- col_name_i/p_from_user

Could you assist?

Comment: Cant understand what exactly you need ?

 Show me your sp result and also your expected result !

Answer (score 5):

As you have didn't mentioned the version so I will assume that you have SQL Server 2012+ version. You can use [WITH RESULT SETS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) property to alter your output column name

**Example**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Test
    AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 1 AS 'ColA', 2 AS 'ColB'
END
```

Now, you can alter the column name by using **WITH RESULT SETS** property

```
 EXEC SP_Test 

EXEC SP_Test WITH RESULT SETS( 
(New_Col1 INT,
NEW_Col2 INT))
```

In case you are using older version of SQL Server then you can dump your stored procedure result set into a temp table or table variable and then you can alias the name(From same above example)

```
DECLARE @Mytest TABLE (New_Col1 INT, New_Col2 INT)

INSERT INTO @Mytest EXEC Sp_Test
SELECT * FROM @Mytest
```

Answer (score 0):

use column alias as below with dynamic sql:

```
declare @q nvarchar(max)
set @q ='select bkt1 as ' + @ipfromuser  +' from table1'
exec(@q)
```

Comment: find solution for sp and coloumn name given from user

Comment: after sp execution change column name

Comment: instead of changing column name after sp execution use aliasing in the select query inside stored procedure as mentioned in my answer

Comment: But my column name are given from user so when write as @ipfromuser then give error

Comment: use dynamic sql then as given in answer